# iOS main menu having the same screens as a fake navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, human-interface-guideline

I've built this app for a client [GP of NOLA](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gp-of-nola/id981223268?mt=8). Where as you can see we have a main menu (first thing you see when opening the app) and when you enter any category you can move between the categories with out the need of going back. It was my first job with this client so I didn't feel like questioning their UI/UX plus time wasn't on our side.

But what could be a good approach for something like this? Using a tab bar with no main menu screen?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE. Please add a screen shot of the interaction, because links are not as useful to the community (they may break in the future)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a basic, no frills UX that works.

The first screen informs the user of their options. When users go into the app they are able to navigate elsewhere easily.  It's simple and works well.

It also looks as if the opening screen promotes the app. Person X likes it, and next time you login, or a few seconds later, you see that Person Y likes it as well. This is good marketing. The app is reinforcing itself as a fun, useful app in the mind of the user: "Hey other people like this. Maybe I should explore further."

The main screen does what it's supposed to - it tells people what's in the app and provides feedback that others find it useful and fun.

Can this be improved upon? Yes. If we have user personas and have tests that show that a large segment of users want - or expect - something much different that what is presented (say they expect / want a schedule of upcoming events) then, of course, work will have to be done.

Comment: Actually those are tweets, not app comments. Still having that screen as "home" doesn't look very useful and not following iOS style.

Comment: There are a great deal of apps that use a "home" menu. In your case, it seems like a pretty good option, although if one page is more likely to be viewed, you could start on that one.